# In TFS 2013, how do I mark a work item as blocked?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2013, how do I mark a work item as blocked - at least at the task level, but more preferably any work item. In other sprint tracking systems it's as easy as right clicking on a work item and selecting "Blocked" and giving a reason. In TFS this doesn't appear to be so straightforward...

Answer (score 4):

We use internally a tag called Blocked, and then use the Styling of the board to color the tag Red. That coloring only works on the board, and doesn't show up in queries or on the backlog, but since we use the boards during standup it works wonderfully well.

We have a story on our backlog to create a real Blocked scenario, and is also tracked on User Voice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2717759-visualize-blocked-task-in-task-board.

Answer (score 0):

TFS relies on a flexible process model that can be customized. Out-of-the-box, there is no status `Blocked` in the available process models. You can customize your work item templates (tasks or others) and introduce the new status and the required transitions. After that you can set the state of your work items to the new state `Blocked` and set up the required queries.

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409273.aspx) for a description on the available customizations.

I'd propose to apply the changes to a test environment first. Please note that changes to the work item templates might result in problems when updating your installation. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Work/customize/customize-work#RelatednotesBeforeyoucustomize_understandthemaintenanceandupgradeimplicationsTFS) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this is available in the Task work item in the CMMI template.  Just copy and paste the xml from the that work item into your Scrum Process Template.  Its reference name is Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked.